# ですかorですが？which one is correct?

Tags: words

While playing League of Legends with some Japanese friends on the JP server, I noticed something interesting. Some of them use "ですが"in chat instead of the correct ”か” I asked them about it and they say that its just that they're lazy and type it the way they hear it, so is it similar to どうして　usually being typed as どして because that's how Japanese people pronounce it in speech, differently from the way its written? i tried searching online for "desuga" and found no results, so its almost certainly incorrect, but native Japanese people are using it so...

Comment: Both are correct, but they mean different things. The explanation they gave you confuses me though.

Comment: There is no way Japanese would write ですが in place of ですか because they don't have the same meaning. Unless we know what the intended meaning was, we can't answer your question.

Comment: I just read about it a bit more, and it seems that some people think that it sounds more polite, feels like adding a "kedo"-ish feeling to the end of a question without making it seem interrogative? Correct me on this I am awfully confused as well (thus why i asked this question)

Comment: I get slightly more than no results: https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&q=%22%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%22

Answer (score 2):

どうして can indeed become どして in a hasty and slangy conversation/chat, but ですか never contracts to ですが. It's no shorter in the first place!

Both ～ですが and ～ですか are perfectly valid Japanese with completely different meanings.

- そうですか。 "Oh, is that so?" / "I see." / "Okay."
- どうしてですか。 "Why is it?"
- そうですが。 ≒ そうですけど。 "That's true, but..." / "Yes, but..." (sort of hedging)
- どうしてですが。 (typo. doesn't make sense.)

Sentence-end が/けど is asked and answered in several existing questions in this site. Please take a look at these.

- [けど at the end of the sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2086/5010)
- [が and けど at end of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27542/5010)
- [けど usage in this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010)

Answer (score 0):

- ですか -> for questioning. For ex: 安いですか Is it cheap?
- ですが -> for reasoning. For ex: 安いですが But it is cheap...

Japanese people tend to use the second one, as it is one form where they are asking indirectly to get better approach/ solution or to ask another thing behind that.